# How to show that a countable noun can be both singular or plural?

Tags: word-choice, determiners

There are times when you don't know how much of something there'll be. There can be

- only one of that thing, OR
- many of that thing.

The number isn't fixed. For example:

> The **officer/officers** who had a hand in this robbery **has/have** not been found out yet. Police investigation is ongoing.
>
> The **student/students**, a teacher is going to assist, **attend/attends** the ceremony with that teacher.

1. Writing like this can be strenuous and time-consuming. **Is there a standard way to deal with this?**
2. And moreover, there's also the trouble with the verb that directly follows it. **What should the `be` verb be — singular or plural?** Note that I've avoided this issue in my examples.

**Note**: I don't know exactly what tags to use. If you edit, please add some explanation as to why you chose or removed a particular tag (...or tags).

Comment: It won't do in prose, but in simple descriptive writing, letters, or journalism, a standard usage is **(s)**; e.g., _"The student(s) a teacher is going to assist must attend the ceremony with that teacher."_

Comment: @P.E.Dant The question has been updated.

Comment: _Be_ is not used in the first example except to form the passive of _find._ In the second, the verb taken by _student/students_ is _attend_, not _be._ In neither example does the form of _be_ (nor any verb) depend upon the number of the noun in question! (If the sentence were _"The officer/officers is/are busy"_, you would have a problem, though.)

Comment: A useful answer depends upon the intended purpose of the writing. Just as with **(s)**, there's nothing wrong with **is/are** in informal writing or even in journalism. In prose, though, you would have to rephrase the sentence to accommodate the uncertainty. _"Any of the officers who were implicated in this robbery..."_, for instance. (Apologies to user3169.)

Comment: @P.E.Dant I've tried to avoid the issue in my examples.

Answer (score 2):

Since the quantity is not known yet, I would look for different determiners to use:

> **Those officers** who had a hand in this robbery haven't been found out yet. *The* police investigation is ongoing.
>   **Any students** a teacher is going to assist must attend the ceremony with that teacher.

Comment: Rather than "articles", you sould have said "determiners", since the term "article" is restricted to a small group: *the, a/n*, and the zero article. Anyway, I liked your answer, which shows that, combined with some indefinite determiner, the plural will include the possibility of something being singular.

Comment: @Gustavson You are right. I edited my answer.